# Is it possible to migrate source code from powerbuilder 12.5 to VSTS directly?

Tags: azure-devops, powerbuilder

we are using powerbuilder 12.5 classic. we will plan to use VSTS(azure devops) in near future.. is it any possible way to use our powerbuilder source code into VSTS ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to migrate source code from powerbuilder 12.5 to VSTS directly?

I am afraid it is impossible to migrate source code from powerbuilder **12.5** to VSTS directly.

As I know, there was a Git MSSCCI provider from PB Software to Git bridge product from PB Software that worked with older versions of Git, but they don't seem to be around anymore:

http://www.pbsoftware.com/index.php/products/powerbuilder-git-msscci-provider/

You could check [this document](https://www.brucearmstrong.org/2017/05/configuring-powerbuilder-projects-to.html) for some details.

Besides, native support for Git (and SVN) was added to the 2017 R2 version of the product by Appeon. I would suggest upgrading to the most recent version of the product if you need to support VSTS(Azure devops):

https://community.appeon.com/index.php/articles/tutorials-articles/2-powerbuilder/183-powerbuilder-2017-r2-new-feature-git-source-control-support

Comment: Great Thanks Leo , it was very helpful information for us..